# Pass attribute to python script with QGIS command line launcher

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, command-line, python-3

I didn't find the answer to this question : is there a way for passing attributes to python script when you try to run it from QGIS command line launch :

```
os.system('qgis --nologo --project project.qgs --code code.py [arg1; arg2; ...]')
```

Because on official documentation there is no word about this possibility. Otherwise do you know a way for passing a layer path as attribute to this `code.py` ?

Comment: No one ? I'm sure it's interesting for someone else !